# How to get the PerformContext from hangfire API

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, hangfire, abp, hangfire-console

In our project we are using aspnetzero template. This template allows a simple but abstracted usage of hangfire. Now we would like to add [Hangfire.Console](https://github.com/pieceofsummer/Hangfire.Console) to our project which would allow us to write logs to hangfires dashboard.

In order to write a log statement to the dashboard console we have to access the PerformContext of the current running job. Unfortunately because of the abstraction in aspnetzero we can't [*inject* the PerformContext](https://github.com/pieceofsummer/Hangfire.Console#log) as it would be planned by hangfire. What we do have access to is the hangfire namespace and all it's static objects.

Therefore my question: Is there a way to get the PerformContext by another way than passing null to the execution method?

**What I have tried so far:**

- By using the *IServerFilter* interface a method *OnPerforming* should be called. But unfortunately this is not the case within aspnetzero background jobs.
- I tried to overwrite/extend the given base class *BackgroundJob< T >* of aspnetzero but with no luck. Perhaps someone can give me a hint in this direction.

Answer (score 2):

I used `JobFilterAttribute`  with a `IServerFilter`.

Example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
 public class HangFirePerformContextAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IServerFilter
{
         private static PerformContext _Context;

        public static PerformContext PerformContext
        {
            get
            {
                return new PerformContext(_Context);
            }
        }
        public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext)
        {
            Context = (PerformContext)filterContext;
            _Context = Context;
        }
        public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext)
        {
            Context = (PerformContext)filterContext;
            _Context = Context;
        }
}
```

And I create a new Class `AsyncBackgroundJobHangFire<TArgs> : AsyncBackgroundJob<TArgs>`

Exemple:

```
    [HangFirePerformContext]
    public abstract class AsyncBackgroundJobHangFire<TArgs> : AsyncBackgroundJob<TArgs>
    {
        public PerformContext Context { get; set; }

        protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(TArgs args)
        {
            Context = HangFirePerformContextAttribute.PerformContext;
            await ExecuteAsync(args, Context);
        }

        protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(TArgs args, PerformContext context);
    }
```

It´s Work

In a Class of job i use a `AsyncBackgroundJobHangFire`

And de method is

```
        [UnitOfWork]
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(string args, PerformContext context)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Just to add to this, you can get it to run on every job by putting this somewhere near your hangfire startup/config (on .NET framework at least!)


`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseFilter(new HangFirePerformContextAttribute());`

Comment: A static PerformContext is perhaps not a good design for Hangfire jobs that are run in parallell, i.e. those who has not added : 

  [DisableConcurrentExecution(0)]

that is - has guard of the Hangfire job cannot be spawned into multiple paralllell jobs

Answer (score 0):

You should never use a static field for that, even if marked with a ThreadStaticAttribute , please refer to this link for more details

https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/use-hangfire-job-id-in-the-code/2621/2